# Repeated crashes on Debian 10

Tags: kernel, freeze

I have a dedicated machine in my garage running LinuxCNC on Debian 10. Recently it's been having repeated crashes and rarely lasts longer than 30 minutes before freezing. I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> and a few other methods but nothing seems to unfreeze it other than a hard reboot. About half the time it boots back up right away, but sometimes it refuses to boot due to Kernel panic.

I dumped syslogs from `/var/log/` but I don't really know what to look for to determine the problem. Can someone take a look and give me some pointers?

I'm not sure the best way to pass logs so I put them in this [Google drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q3HY25b3YXb5Z2Em2hD1DI5Wy7lRUf4E?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you possibly copy the Kernel Panic and add it as an update here.  After that's inspected, use [pastebininit](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=153400) to upload a `dmesg`.  Maybe we can match something in the panic to something in the `dmesg`

Comment: It really sounds like your system is borked and needs to be replaced. As ever though, reseat as many components as you can & retest. And remember to take correct esd precautions.